# Power BI - Average of only some rows

Tags: powerbi, average

I have a table like this in Power BI:

```
         Minutes  Distance
Player 1    90       800         
Player 2    40       300         
Player 3    75       600    
Player 4    55       500
```

I would like to calculate the average of the distance of only the players who has played more than 70 minutes (excluding in this case Player 2 and Player 4 of the calculation of average). What's the best way to do this? A new measure with what formula exactly? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you can use [CALCULATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/calculate-function-dax) function and pass a filter to it, to include only the rows, where `Minutes` is greater than 70. Then you can calculate the average distance using [AVERAGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/average-function-dax) function, so the measure can be something like this (assuming your table is named `Table`):

```
Average Distance = CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Table'[Distance]), 'Table'[Minutes] > 70)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I solved with that solution :)